# Should I use interfaces for data classes in API packages?

Tags: java, api-design, software-design

I'm designing an API to cover it with tests in the future.

My service method requires some data classes:

```java
public interface Service {
   GetUserResponse getUser(GetUserQuery query);
}
```

`GetUserResponse` and `GetUserQuery` are just structures carrying data.

Should I create them as interface or POJO with setters, getters, etc.?

Also, if the latter, where to place them? In the API module or a one with implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It's opinion, but I don't agree with your choices.

1. "Service" - too generic, not necessarily about data.  Those usually mean SOAP or, better yet, REST, to me.
2. The query object?  I think it's a better contract to spell out what the user should pass.  Don't worry about being flexible; prefer being clear.
3. I'd expect the return value from getUser to be a User.

Here's what I'd do:

```
public interface UserRepository {  
    List<User> find();
    User find(Integer id);
    List<User> find(String lastName);
    Integer save(User user);
    void update(User user);
    void delete(Integer id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. However, this answer doesn't state what exactly input arguments should be. In your example, what's the `User`? An interface or a class?

Comment: I know, but that's my point: they're easy to guess, easy to write.  One uses interfaces to separate API from implementation, usually when there could be several implementations with the same API.  Model objects like User don't often fit that bill.  My User would be a class until I found it necessary to have different behaviors.  Design extremes are not good.  I don't like to be too literal or too abstract.  I try to find a useful balance.